# Evaluate a block in a certain scope and pass an argument

Tags: ruby, block

For example, let's say I have

```
block = proc { |n| "#{downcase} #{n}" }
```

Now I want to evaluate that block in the scope of a `String`, but pass that block a variable. I know how to do the first part:

```
"Foo".instance_eval(&block)
```

But how to also pass a variable to that block?

I tried

```
"Foo".instance_eval { block.call(3) }
```

But it didn't work, it wasn't in the scope of the `String`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`instance_exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec) instead:

> **instance_exec(arg...) {|var...| block } → obj**
>
> Executes the given block within the context of the receiver (*obj*). In order to set the context, the variable `self` is set to *obj* while the code is executing, giving the code access to *obj*’s instance variables. Arguments are passed as block parameters.

So this will make it go:

```
"Foo".instance_exec(3, &block)
```

and give you the `'foo 3'` that you desire.

The problem with this:

```
"Foo".instance_eval { block.call(3) }
```

is that `self` will be `"Foo"` inside `{ block.call(3) }` but not inside `block`, `block` will retain whatever `self` was when `block` was defined; there's nothing in `block.call(3)` that forces a context so `self` doesn't change. For example, given this:

```
class C
  def m
    proc { |n| "#{downcase} #{n}" }
  end
end
c = C.new
"Foo".instance_eval { c.m.call(3) }
```

When the proc is called, `self` will be `c` because that's what `self` was when the proc was defined (i.e. when `m` was called). What `self` is inside the `instance_eval` block doesn't have any effect on `self` inside the proc.

Comment: @janko-m: I just added a bit more discussion that might be of interest.